How do I add Metadata in my custom prebuilt application docker image in Spring cloud dataflow
I have customized the JDBC-SOURCE-KAFKA Stream application project and ran the maven commands to generate the Main jar and Metadata jar.
After importing as --URI and --METADATA-URI I can see the configurable options in the UI like this 
But Now my use case is to achieve this using docker image that's where the problem is.
Now I am using this newly built jar as docker image and then providing metadata URI as maven jar while registering it like below:

URI - docker:my-image-name:latest
METADATA URI - mavem:my-metadata-jar:latest

This work locally fine I can see the meta data but when I am creating a image and pushing it to my private registry and then registering it I can't see the configurable metadata options like JDBC URL and all. 
I have customized this application.
I tried the documentation references which are still unclear to me where to how deal with metadata using docker.
Let me know what I am missing !!

It is important that you configure your private Maven Repository
In order to be able to access the registered maven metadata jar.
If you create a container image using spring-boot:build-image and your application has dataflow-configuration-metadata.properties the Java Buildpack will add image labels with specific names that dataflow server will use to retrieve the metadata.
